# Fancy image viewer for iPhone, how to do?

Tags: iphone

Hello any one know component to make this kind of image viewer ? Or maybe some code, or any help ?

http://img860.imageshack.us/i/44940170.jpg

Comment: This would be called a "Cover-flow" type interface. google a bit and you'll find some sample code around for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image viewer diagram you have is based on Apple's cover flow. There are a few open source projects which replicate this. I have used [OpenFlow](https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow) before and it is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Flow cover would be another example:

http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m